Bat file script to loop through folders and build projects
I am having folder structure like below.
My current folder structure
Master
   FolderA
     A.csproj
   FolderB
     FolderBA
      BA.csproj
     FolderBC
      BC.csproj  
   FolderC
     C.csproj
 

Please let me know if its possible to loop through folders to clean and rebuild the projects.
I have seen some commands but not sure how to acheive this
    for /f "delims=" %x in ('dir /s /b *.csproj') do if exist %x 
 cd %Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe %x /t:rebuild

But the above is giving error.
My expectation during for loop is to navigate to msbuild path and rebuild the variable %x.
Please let me know how can we do this in aloop

I would highly recommend powershell over .bat for scripting on windows. But a solution file is most likely the way to go, especially if the projects are somehow related.

I am looking in bat file  with looping

why? batch script is quite limited, and in my experience, not used much nowdays. Powershell on the other hand is much newer, better designed, and allow you to call any .net function.

One alternative is to create a solution file at the root folder.
Master
   FolderA
     A.csproj
   FolderB
     FolderBA
      BA.csproj
     FolderBC
      BC.csproj  
   FolderC
     C.csproj
   Master.sln

Do:
dotnet new sln
dotnet sln add FolderA\A.csproj
dotnet sln add FolderB\FolderBA\BA.csproj
dotnet sln add FolderB\FolderBC\BC.csproj
dotnet sln add FolderC\C.csproj

With a single solution, simply do this at the root:
dotnet clean

OR, do:
FOR %%G IN (FolderA\\A.csproj FolderB\\FolderA\\BA.csproj) DO msbuild %%G

I recommend adding msbuild to the PATH. But, keep in mind this is not the typical approach.

projects are not linked with a single solution.Please let me know how can we do using for loop

I tried this code snippet and its working
set ROOT_DIR=%~dp0  // got me the path for Master

cd %ROOT_DIR% //Navigated to path and looped through 
set MSBUILDPATH= "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b *.csproj') do if exist %%x (
    
    call %MSBUILDPATH% %%x /t:rebuild
    
)

